# Parse pdf extraction into csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv, parsing, pdftotext

I am still a newbie to Python. I am trying to develop a generic pdf-scraper to csv that is organized by the columns containing: page number and paragraphs.

I'm using the PyMuPDF library and I have managed to extract all the text. But I have no clue how to parse the text and write it into csv:

```
page number, paragraph
page number, paragraph
page number, paragraph
```

Luckily there is a structure. Each paragraph ends with an enter (\n). Each page ends with a page number followed by an enter (\n). I would like to include headers as well but they are harder to delimit.

```
import fitz
import csv

pdf = '/file/path.pdf'
doc = fitz.open(pdf)

for page in doc:
    text = page.getText(text)
    print (text)
```

Comment: Wow, that makes my search a bit more difficult. I guess, it would suggest that the paragraphs are delimited by an x-range of letters and spaces and an x-amount of rows (no more than. The digits followed by empty space is a good delimiter for a page. Still lost. Any handy reading material? Or piece of code I can adapt?

Comment: You could look into [layout parsing](https://layout-parser.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks. Layout parsing seems to be what I need.